# Can't access server, 2FA rejecting verification codes and back-up codes don't work

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have just configured the google-authenticator 2FA for a server I have and am now unable to sign in as the connections are being rejected by.

I get the following message:

> Received disconnect from SERVER: 2: Too many authentication failures
>   for USER

I have tried multiple times to add the key to authenticator and neither the keys or back-up codes are able to authenticate. It's not a time issue as the server is on the correct time and as far as i know the back-up codes work regardless of any time issues.

Any help would be great, annoyingly I forgot to add an extra user as I reset the server the other day so there is only one user on the box.

Comment: Is this before or after you've entered the 2FA code? Do you use an SSH key or a password?

Comment: post the whole debug log.

Comment: I have an SSH key that I use and worked before setting up the 2FA and I get the error after entering the details.

I've tried the same thing on another box but added another user before setting it up, the user is able to sign in with 2FA however the same issue happens for root.

Comment: I'm now also trying [duo for the 2FA](https://duo.com) as there's push to accept functionality and the same issue seems to happen for root and as of yet I can't get it working for a different user. [Here's the log for root](https://ghostbin.com/paste/9z2df).

I receive the push request and the connection pauses but on accepting the request the SSH connection is terminated.

Comment: Turns out my authorized_keys file had root ownership for some reason, correcting the permissions allows for Key and 2FA access for the user account but not root. I'm thinking that's a good place to be but am wondering why root doesn't work. [here's the very verbose log](https://ghostbin.com/paste/m9b9k)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to delete and rebuild the server instance I was using. This is because the default settings for the root user prevented any other form of authentication but SSH-Key authentication and as such I was locked out of the server.

This means that under the default settings of the Ubuntu build from scaleway it is not possible to set up 2FA for the root user. It is possible however for users that are created, by following the instructions for Duo or Google two-factor.

I will be using Duo in future as it allows for pushing to the app for the 2FA and a simple button accept rather than typing in a verification key. Just ensure that to test the configuration while keeping an SSH connection open to prevent being locked out through a mistake.